# How to wrap all fragments (that are not inside of <div> or <h>) with <p>?

Tags: php, regex, word-wrap

I have a code:

```
$html = 
'<h1>Headline</h1>
That should be paragraph 1.

That should be paragraph 2.

<div>Something.</div>
That should be paragraph 3.
';
```

And I want to change it into:

```
$html = 
'<h1>Headline</h1>
<p>That should be paragraph 1.</p>

<p>That should be paragraph 2.</p>

<div>Something.</div>
<p>That should be paragraph 3.</p>
';
```

**But how to achieve it in PHP?**

I was thinking about replacing each empty line with `<p>`, `</p>`, or `</p><p>`, based on some counter of open/close paragraphs. But that would force user to make such new lines after every `</h1>`.

Maybe some **regular expression** would do the job without limiting user to "you have to make new lines after `</h1>` and before `<h1>`"?

**The more general the approach is, the better.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below negative lookahead asserts that the  line won't contain `<h1>` or `<div>` tags. If yes, then it capture the contents of whole line into group 1.

```
^(?!.*?(?:<h1>|<div>))(.+)$
```

Replacement string:

```
<p>$1</p>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sR3vQ4/3)

**Code:**

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
<h1>Headline</h1>
That should be paragraph 1.

That should be paragraph 2.

<div>Something.</div>
That should be paragraph 3.
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~^(?!.*?(?:<h1>|<div>))(.+)$~m', '<p>$1</p>', $string)
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<h1>Headline</h1>
<p>That should be paragraph 1.</p>

<p>That should be paragraph 2.</p>

<div>Something.</div>
<p>That should be paragraph 3.</p>
```